# How to order by variable in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I want to order my table in specific way.

mytable
column 1 distinct values:

```
completed,in-progress,yetstart,yetfinish
```

I want to order by

```
yetstart,in-progress,completed,yetfinish
```

in this sequence

Comment: what is the significance on this sorting ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [**FIELD()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function to **ORDER BY** columns data:

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
ORDER BY FIELD(column1, 'yetstart', 'in-progress', 'completed', 'yetfinish');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when your_column = 'yetstart' then 1 
              when your_column = 'in-progress' then 2 
              when your_column = 'completed' then 3
              when your_column = 'yetfinish' then 4
              else 5
         end
```

Comment: field seems more elegant somehow

Comment: Yes. Case is only better if there are other values that should be sorted to the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
  ORDER BY field_name1 DESC, field_name2 DESC;
```